# how to pass static value into dynamic on basis of column value in azure databricks

Tags: azure, apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks

how to pass static value into dynamic on basis of column value in Azure Databricks. Currently, I have 13 notebook and its scheduled ,so I want to schedule only one notebook and In addition, data of column( 13 rows) which I defined separate in 13 notebook so how I dynamically pass that value .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [create different jobs](https://docs.databricks.com/jobs.html#create-a-job) that refer the single notebook, pass parameters to a job and then retrieve these parameters using [Databricks Widgets](https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/widgets.html) (widgets are available for all languages). In the notebook it will look as following (for example, in Python):

```py
# this is necessary only if you execute notebook interactively
dbutils.widgets.text("param1_name", "default_value", "description")
# get job parameter
param1 = dbutils.widgets.get("param1_name")
# ... use param1
```